# react-native:i get error can't find variable:'title

Tags: react-native

when i learn react-native,i get the error

> 'title' is not found

but i defined title.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,TextInput} from 'react-native';
import SubmitButton from './SubmitButton';
import {white,black,gray} from '../utils/colors';
import {saveDeckTitle} from '../utils/api';
import {addDeck} from '../Actions';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
 class NewDeck extends Component{
 state={
    title:''
  };
 submit=()=>{
   const {title}=this.state;
   saveDeckTitle(title);
   this.props.dispatch(addDeck(title));
 };

render(){
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.question}>What is the title of your new 
deck?</Text>
            <Text style={{marginTop:50,alignSelf:'flex- 
start',fontSize:20}}>Deck Title</Text>
            <TextInput
                style={styles.textInput}
                onChangeText={(title) => {this.setState({title})}}
                value={this.state.title}
                placeholder='Deck Title'
                placeholderTextColor={gray}
                underlineColorAndroid={gray}
                keyboardType="default"
            />
            <Text style={{height:200}}/>
            <SubmitButton style={styles.submitBtn}  onPress= 
{this.submit}>Submit</SubmitButton>
            <Text>{this.state.title}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

in action:

```
export const ADD_DECK='ADD_DECK';

export function addDeck(title) {
  return {
    type:ADD_DECK,
    title
}
```

the error like this:

> can't find variable:'title'

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idKvj.png)

when i didn't add `'this.props.dispatch(addDeck(title));'` it works well,i want to know why i **get this error**

Comment: Can you please tell the exact error in browser?

Comment: in the second snippet, you did probably typo, you missing `}` at the end. 

anyway, could you please 
```submit=()=>{
console.log('state', this.state, 'props', this.props);
   const {title}=this.state;
``` console.log here?